# i need some help about plsql functions in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

this is my code for procedure. i have created two tables as Stud_Marks and Result with some data in it...and then i have created this procedure. at run time it shows error for "object SYS.FIND_CLASS is invalid".

```
  SQL> create or replace procedure find_class(roll IN number) IS


2  tm number (10);
  3  begin
  4  select total_marks into tm from stud_marks where name IN(select name from result where roll=roll_no);
  5  if(tm<=1500 and tm>=990)then
  6  update result set class='distin' where roll_no=roll;
  7  elseif(tm>900 and tm<989)then
  8  update result set class='first' where roll_no=roll;
  9  elseif(tm<=899 and tm>=825)then
 10  update result set class='second' where roll_no=roll;
 11  end if;
 12  exception when no_data_found then
 13  dbms_output.put_line('roll no is not matched with the entry');
14  end;
 15  /




[enter image description here][1]
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors
```

.

```
SQL> declare



2  r number(10);
  3  begin
  4  r:=&roll_no;
  5  find_class(r);
  6  end;
  7  /





Enter value for roll_no: 1
old   4: r:=&roll_no;
new   4: r:=1;
find_class(r);




*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00905: object SYS.FIND_CLASS is invalid
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

then i am getting an error for find_class(r)..why???

Comment: `object SYS.FIND_CLASS is invalid`.  Creating your objects under the `SYS` schema is very, very bad.  You will weep bitter tears if you continue to use that account.  Create a new database account and use it.

Comment: `if(tm<=1500 and tm>=990)` can be written more simply as `if tm between 990 and 1500`. Perhaps the whole thing would be clearer written in ascending order, maybe as a single `update` with a `case` expression. Is `989` excluded on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the procedure, you must make sure it is valid. Yours isn't so Oracle raises an error.

Once you created it, you got a message saying

> Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors

You should have checked what's wrong by running command

```
show err
```

I reformatted code you posted - see how it is easier to read:

```
create or replace procedure find_class(roll IN number) IS
  tm number (10);
begin
  select total_marks 
    into tm 
    from stud_marks 
    where name IN (select name 
                   from result 
                   where roll = roll_no
                  );

  if (tm <= 1500 and tm >= 990)then
     update result set 
       class = 'distin' 
       where roll_no = roll;
  elsif (tm > 900 and tm < 989) then        --> ELSIF, not ELSEIF
     update result set 
       class = 'first' 
       where roll_no = roll;
  elsif (tm <= 899 and tm >= 825) then      --> ELSIF, not ELSEIF
     update result set 
       class = 'second' 
       where roll_no = roll;
   end if;

exception when no_data_found then
  dbms_output.put_line('roll no is not matched with the entry');
end;
```

Apparently, you used `ELSEIF` while it should be `ELSIF`. I don't know whether that's the only error as I don't have your tables - you'll find that out. Don't forget to `show err` if necessary!

So, once it is created without errors, you can call it and see what it does.

P.S. Forgot to mention: why do you do it connected as `SYS`? That user owns the database and should **not** be used for *development* or *educational* purposes. You should use one of predefined users (such as `Scott` or `HR`) or create your own user. Leave `SYS` alone.